# How to uninstall Ubuntu 9.10 from Win XP / Wubi?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu 9.10 via a disk onto a Windows XP computer.

Windows is in the first partition. I later installed Ubntu 12.10 via Wubi

When the compuuter boots I pick from Ubuntu or Windows on SDA1.

When I boot Windows my Wubi (12.10) option shows up asking me if I want to use Ubuntu 12.10 or Windows.

I am wondering how I remove Ubuntu 9.10 from the computer but keep 12.10(Wubi) while using Windows XP.

Comment: Is 9.10 on it's own partition?

Comment: Please provide more detail so we can understand your question: what is the partition setup and where are each of the 3 OSs you mention installed? Specifically, did you use WUBI to install 9.10 and 12.10 within Windows, or did you install them separately on their own partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to uninstall a Wubi installation, you can do so from within Windows the same way you would uninstall a program from windows. Its somewhere in control panel. [Read this for more information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_uninstall_Wubi.3F)

To uninstall a non Wubi installation, try using [OS-uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller#A2nd_option_%3a_install_OS-Uninstaller_in_Ubuntu). You need to boot into a live CD or another Ubuntu installation to us it. OS-uninstaller will not be able to detect a Wubi installation and therefore runs no risk of damaging it.

Comment: I want to uninstall 9.10 which was installed by a disc, not Wubi.

Comment: OS-uninstaller worked. Thank you!